# windows phone app navigating to an instance of page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

can i use navigation service to navigate to object of page in windows phone 8 unlike giving a Uri like

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());
```

instead of

```
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

The method `this.NavigationService.Navigate` takes only one parameter which is a `Uri`.

Comment: k is there any way to navigate with objects of page

Comment: I don't think so, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: You can define a mapping between Page object and corresponding Uri, then create an extension method for NavigationService that allows you to pass the Page you want to navigate to.

Comment: am using same instant of page several times to navigate in app,it will lead to infinite number of pages and will lead to heavy memory

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. But I am pretty sure what you ask is not going to solve your problem, you will need to edit your question to exactly what the issue is.